# Why doesn't warning C4131 (old-style function) warn if there's no argument?

Tags: c, visual-c++, warnings

My understanding of the warning for old-style function declarations is that they don't constitute a prototype, which in turn means that checking of the arguments passed to it is not being done.

As far as I know this is the case if no argument (not even `void`) is included too, that is:

```
void bar()
{
}

void foo(int x)
{
   bar(x);
}
```

would not require failure or even diagnosis. I feel this deserves as much warning as any old-style definition.

But MSVC++ doesn't warn for this type of function definition, why? They actually seem to accept faults like the above without warning.

Comment: MSVC++ has a historical C mode, but don't expect too much from it. As the name says, it really is a C++ compiler, and C++ doesn't have "prototypes".

Comment: I got _warning C4098: 'foo' : 'void' function returning a value_ from VS2013 in "C" mode.

Comment: @jwdonahue the code was misleading, I corrected the question.

Comment: @MSalters even non MS compilers don't issue any errors/warning: [live sample here](https://www.ideone.com/exN4zE).

Comment: @MSalters, "prototype" is just another name for "declaration" and C++ definitely has them.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, but that because you don't use `-Wold-style-definition`. With the warning enabled it does warn. Note that MSVC++ doesn't warn for C4131 whatsoever if you don't enable it somehow.

Comment: @MSalters That's true, but still it has the C4131 warning which doesn't apply to C++. The question is why they don't warn on this particular case which AFAIK is basically equally dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most important thing to notice here is that compilers still **must** accept "old style" function declarators. The relevant part of the grammar is this:

**N1570 (latest C11-draft) §6.7.6 p1**:

> *direct-declarator:*
>           [...]
>           *direct-declarator* `(` *identifier-list*<sub>*opt*</sub> `)`

But it is marked obsolete (**§6.11.6 p1**):

> The use of function definitions with separate parameter identifier and declaration lists
>   (not prototype-format parameter type and identifier declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

So, this strongly suggests compilers should at least be able to warn about it. As for why a specific compiler doesn't do it, you have to ask the manufacturer or drop a bug report / feature request.

Specifically for MSVC, I can only guess it's another symptom of Microsoft's focus on C++. In C++, an empty parameter list *indeed* means "this function has no parameters" and it's quite possible Microsoft just reused the code for generating the warnings from C++. But again, this is guessing.